# Setting all the values of the objects to double type in R session

Tags: r

How can one set all the objects/outputs' values to a double in R session.

Suppose `a` is a vector , it should return the double values even if the elements are integers.

After that suppose if I define a matrix, say `mm` then all the elements in the matrix should appear as double.

E.g.

Suppose `mm` is the matrix

```
mm=matrix(1:10, nrow=2)
> mm
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10
```

my desired output is:

```
> mm
         [,1]   [,2]    [,3]  [,4]   [,5]
    [1,]    1.0    3.0    5.0    7.0    9.0
    [2,]    2.0    4.0    6.0    8.0   10.0
```

Can anyone answer this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try: mm <- matrix(as.double(1:10), nrow=2)

Answer (score 0):

Try: `mm <- matrix(as.double(1:10), nrow=2)` 
then check via `typeof(mm)`
`# "double"`

Comment: If it is an existing matrix - since all elements of a matrix maust be of the same type recast one element e.g. mm[1] <- as.double(mm[1])
Then check typeof(mm) ...

Comment: If formatting is your major concern e.g. for exporting etc. maybe try: formatC(mm, digits=2, format="f")

Comment: I think it should be `print(formatC(mm, digits = 1, format = "f"), quote = FALSE)`

Comment: Thank you for your response everyone, This would be specific case for a matrix. Can I do something globally, In the beginning of R session so that I every time I print some object I don't have to format it?